# Error while running Django project in python files

Tags: python, django, django-forms, virtualenv, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to run a django app, in a `virtualenv`, but by running

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I face this error:

```
File "/home/sahar/Rtis/rtisenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tinymce
/widgets.py", line 16, in <module>
    from django.forms.utils import flatatt
ImportError: No module named utils
```

could anyone help to solve this problem? I've been searching through the net a long time and still no change!

Comment: what is your django version?

Comment: it's 1.4.22, as I read, this should be django.forms.util in this version, but both the widget.py file -which call the function flatatt- and django.forms.util are the installed part and it's not related to my project, so I'm really get confused!

Comment: yup as its deprecated from django 1.7 and you are using a latest version of tinymce but your django version is too old, so update your django version to 1.11 or atleast 1.10

Comment: please update your Django version.

Comment: thank you so much, problem solved, however I downgrade the tinymce instead of upgrading the django. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you might be using an old, unsupported version of Django. The module has been `django.forms.utils` [since Django 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/#util-modules-renamed-to-utils). In earlier versions it was `django.forms.util`.

You are getting the error because your installed version of django-tinymce [does not support your version of Django](https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce/blob/master/CHANGELOG.rst#250-2017-01-23). You could try installing an earlier version of tinymce, but really your priority should be to upgrade to a modern version of Django which receives security updates. In June 2017, that means Django 1.8 LTS, 1.11 LTS or 1.10.

Comment: thank you so much, by downgrading i could solve my problem :)